# Using the logical indexing for 2D list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use logical indexing in the 2D list, but it seems not to support this feature.

### The data

```
# For example
twoDimList = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

### Original source

```
for rowIdx in range(0, len(twoDimList)):
    for colIdx in range(0, len(twoDimList[rowIdx])):
        if twoDimList[rowIdx][colIdx] == 0:
            twoDimList[rowIdx][colIdx] = np.nan
```

### My Ideal solution

```
twoDimList[twoDimList == 0] = numpy.nan # In fact, it's illegal.
```

How can I make this design pattern more clever.

Comment: Is `twoDimList` a numpy array?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Dear sir, the variable like `twoDimList = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, the **list is not a numpy array**. You can construct one with:

```
import numpy as np

# convert the 2d Python list into a numpy array
twoDimList = np.array(twoDimList,dtype=np.float)

twoDimList[twoDimList == 0] = np.nan
```

The `dtype` is crucial here: if you do not specify it, numpy will assume you have given it a matrix of *integers*, and the integers do not have a NaN (only for floats a NaN is defined).

You can also give the numpy array another variable name (but the changes done in the numpy array will not reflect on the original Python list).

If your original list is (based on your sample data):

```
twoDimList = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
```

we get:

```
>>> twoDimList = [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> twoDimList = np.array(twoDimList,dtype=np.float)
>>> twoDimList[twoDimList == 0] = np.nan
>>> twoDimList
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,   1.,   1.],
       [ nan,   1.,   1.,   1.]])
```

Comment: Dear sir, thank your answer. I succeed now, but got the error message. `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. And I change my original elements in the array to float is working.

Comment: @Husky: that should be solved with the `dtype` parameter.

Comment: It's working and perfect. Thanks for your answering :]